# Error no: 1064 while uploading excel sheet

Tags: mysql, opencart

```
Notice: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=IF(K2>0,"7","5"),'PNW Arms',152,'data/Products Pictures/pnwpic300blkhnt125btip2' at line 1
Error No: 1064
INSERT INTO `product` (`product_id`,`quantity`,`sku`,`upc`,`ean`,`jan`,`isbn`,`mpn`,`location`,`stock_status_id`,`model`,`manufacturer_id`,`image`,`shipping`,`price`,`points`,`date_added`,`date_modified`,`date_available`,`weight`,`weight_class_id`,`status`,`tax_class_id`,`viewed`,`length`,`width`,`height`,`length_class_id`,`sort_order`,`subtract`,`minimum`) VALUES (1,5,'93579','855118002572','','','83964','300BLKHNT125BTIP20','',=IF(K2>0,"7","5"),'PNW Arms',152,'data/Products Pictures/pnwpic300blkhnt125btip20.jpg',1,23.3625,0,NOW(),NOW(),NOW(),0.8,5,0,11,0,5,2.625,1.5,'3','1','0','1'); in /hermes/bosweb26a/b1700/ipg.athetralcom/Athetral/system/database/mysql.php on line 49
```

I am trying to import excel sheet in opencart admin panel. I got this error only when I put formulas in my excel sheet. I tried without formula and import the excel sheet and it worked but not with FORMULA. Please help me to find out the root cause of this error. In addition, I am a dropshipper with around 40k products in the excel sheet. When I try to upload the excel sheet at the same time with 40 k products, it doesn’t give me any error and I get blank page (nothing uploads or happens). Please let me know from which file is this error coming so I can fix it. Please give me your suggestions.

Comment: What is this `=IF(K2>0,"7","5")` value? What is `K2`? Is it a column? I never saw such an `INSERT INTO` value... Which does not mean it cannot work but at least I am curious about the `K2` and the `=` sign at the start...

Comment: try to remove = before IF statement.

Comment: btw this is mysql error, so put mysql tag. I dont see what this error have to do with opencart?

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the query (insert values) so it looks like this (You do not have to use breaklines as I did, I did it just for better recognition) - notice the comment I added behind the concrete value to be changed:

```sql
INSERT INTO `product` 
    (`product_id`
    ,`quantity`
    ,`sku`
    ,`upc`
    ,`ean`
    ,`jan`
    ,`isbn`
    ,`mpn`
    ,`location`
    ,`stock_status_id`
    ,`model`
    ,`manufacturer_id`
    ,`image`
    ,`shipping`
    ,`price`
    ,`points`
    ,`date_added`
    ,`date_modified`
    ,`date_available`
    ,`weight`
    ,`weight_class_id`
    ,`status`
    ,`tax_class_id`
    ,`viewed`
    ,`length`
    ,`width`
    ,`height`
    ,`length_class_id`
    ,`sort_order`
    ,`subtract`
    ,`minimum`) 
VALUES 
    (1
    ,5
    ,'93579'
    ,'855118002572'
    ,''
    ,''
    ,'83964'
    ,'300BLKHNT125BTIP20'
    ,''
    ,IF(K2 > 0, '7', '5') /* <-- THIS VALUE CHANGED */
    ,'PNW Arms'
    ,152
    ,'data/Products Pictures/pnwpic300blkhnt125btip20.jpg'
    ,1
    ,23.3625
    ,0
    ,NOW()
    ,NOW()
    ,NOW()
    ,0.8
    ,5
    ,0
    ,11
    ,0
    ,5
    ,2.625
    ,1.5
    ,'3'
    ,'1'
    ,'0'
    ,'1')
```

But still I am curious what is this `K2` value - does the `product` table contain such a column???

Answer (score 0):

this IF statement will work in excel with K2 as column id, but there is no sense when it comes to SQL .

Can't you copy paste formulas a value in excel then try uploading the file ?

---

If you like this answer , Please visit our site http://punegrocery.in

Comment: in case you want to keep the formulas then replace K2 with the column name from the MySQL table.